# Is code generation really useful for general (crud based) agile development?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, code-generation, agile

I was reading the Scott Hanselman's article (http://www.hanselman.com/blog/T4TextTemplateTransformationToolkitCodeGenerationBestKeptVisualStudioSecret.aspx) then I got me thinking about T4, CodeSmith and code generation ... So, is that a good choice for saving dev-time, maintenance-time , money, architectural issues, etc ?

Thanks for replying ...

Comment: You might want to add tags to show what languages you're interested in.  Some of us use languages that are good enough that code generation isn't necessary at all.

Comment: How are agile and codegeneration mixed together? Everything that saves `time` is good.

Comment: I don't know how mixed together they are ... I want to know if they can be mixed too .. This is part of the question ...

Comment: @Tocco: They have almost nothing to do with each other.  Agile and code generation are independent.  Use one, use the other, or use both.  No relationship.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code generation is good whenever you have some set of tasks that are similar in some regular way, and the time to implement the generator is less than the time to build or maintain the tasks.

If you have 100 record types, and want a CRUD tool to provide record inspectors/updates, a generator could be pretty handy.   If you have 3 and they are stable, a generator is a waste of time.

Comment: Ok @Ira Baxter, but I can do a CRUD for those 100 record types with EF(Entity Framework, .net), NHibernate(.net), Hibernate (java), etc. So the question is, what to choose: ORM or Code Generation for DAL. (this is merely a sample)

Comment: So you get to make a judgement call: is NHibernate short/long term better than whatever DAL is (I assume its a generator framework)? You need to decide based on information I don't have, which is the quality/completeness of the code generator, the rate of change of the system that the ORM/Generator is part of, etc.  Fundamentally if it isn't a clear win, you should do it, regardless of ORM or code generation; the point is leverage during initial construction and downstream maintenance.

Comment: If i use a code generation tool to create a DAL, once created, someone (indisciplined) can place business rules on DAL generated code ... With a ORM your DAL is (almost) untouchable ... IMO  

So ... for c# .net developers i don't see great benefits ...

Comment: @Tocco You should use a code generation approach coupled with a modeling approach. Model-based code generators are maintainable. Also, the model should be the "source", ensuring that no "indisciplined" developer can add custom code where he shouldn't. ABSE is one such approach that I know, but there are probably others.

Answer (score 0):

> So, is that a good choice for saving dev-time, maintenance-time , money, architectural issues, etc ?

No.

A language which doesn't rely on code generation is a good choice for saving developer time, maintenance time, money and reducing architectural issues.

Comment: I don't understand your assertion. Virtually no language I know of relies on code generation. Code generation usually starts with some kind of descriptive formalism ("DSL") that your favorite langauge by definition doesn't encode well, and often produces complex code in your language or perhaps another that is difficult for one to code or maintain well manually. SQL is good. XAML is good. CORBA is good. Whole- and partial- array (data parallel) arithmetic is good. OpenMP is good. How do you code these things in your favorite langauge?

Comment: @Ira Baxter: First, the question presumes that code generation is somehow relied upon.  If it wasn't relied upon, it wouldn't even be the topic of a question, would it?  Second, I use Python.  DSL's (while they may exist in Python) are very rare (and I have never used one).  SQL doesn't lead to code generation that I see; Python programmers seem to have no use for XAML;  CORBA seems to have been supplanted by RESTful web services.  So, code generation is almost completely irrelevant for Python developers.  The question seems to presume it's relied upon, but languages don't make use of it.

Comment: @SLott: (@S<dot>Lott vanishes, SO bug?) The question as posed seems to be asking if code generation can help, as opposed to the implied alternative of no code generation.  SQL does generate code, at least if your database is any good; yes you don't see it but it is real enough.  I agree Python programmers don't (have any) use XAML; surely they wish to build complex UIs; so how is it done in Python?  CORBA has uses beyond just web services in building integrated applications.   Perhaps you operate in world where you need none of this kind of stuff but that would be a surprise to me.

Comment: @Ira Baxter: SQL does not generate any Python code that I can see, or have to worry about.  It may do something in the database, but that's not part of my application, it's just a web service, nothing more.  CORBA has had no impact on any of the web services I've written or used for the past few years.  Complex UI's are done with Python code directly, not a DSL and generated code.  I have not used code generation except in a very contrived way to turn a spreadsheet into unit test  cases.